# FileNotFoundError when running virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

When I run the command `python -m virtualenv venv`

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 2328, in <module>main()
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main symlink=option.symlink)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment site_packages=site-packaged clear= clear, symlink=simlink
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1147, in install_python writefile(site_filename_dst, SITE_PY)
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 362, in writefile with open(dest, 'wb') as F:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\python\\sites\\venv\\python35.zip\\site.py'
```

When I navigate to the 'venv' folder the file structure is completely unpopulated with only C:\Python\sites\venv\Lib\site-packages (which is completely empty)

I have tried re-installing virtualenv and googling the issue with no avail. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly installed the python on your machine? I also run into a similar issue earlier. It was caused by my python installation. 
You see if you check your python path and go to the `Lib` folder, I assume there was no `site.py`. You can:

- reinstalled your python, make sure it has correctly installed (check the `Lib` and `Script` folder)
- correct your python path to your user/system environment: I assume you are using Window OSX, e.g: `setx PYTHONHOME "C:\<your_python_path>"`; add that to your path: `setx PATH "%PATH%;%PYTHONHOME%"`
- Don't forget to add the Script path as well, if you want to access `pip` without `python -m`

Cheers!!